# Crossword puzzle using JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, css, crossword

[Please see this image to read the actual assignment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B00URazV5RS1djB2NFZrclMwb0k/view?usp=sharing)

I need to make this crossword puzzle, I am totally new in IT, however I have been trying very hard to make this as I have to submit this as an assignment to get a job in web development. I am having a hard time deciding to use a HTML table with background color changed for the puzzle or do I make a javascript multidimensional array to make this crossword.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross word Puzzel</title>
<style>
#puzzel {
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#cross{
 text-align: center;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid white;
}


#buttons{
 width:30%;
 float: right;

}
tr{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leftBox{
 float: left;
 width:50%
 height: 50%;
}
#rightBox{
 float: left;
}
#butt{
 width: 100px;
 padding:20px;
}
table{
 padding:20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftBox">
<table id="puzzel">
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="rightBox">
<table>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Clear All"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Check"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Solve"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Clue"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And also I have tried this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross word Puzzel</title>
<style>
#puzzel {
 width:330px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#cross{
 text-align: center;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid white;
}


#buttons{
 width:30%;
 float: right;

}
tr{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leftBox{
 float: left; 
}
#rightBox{
 float: left;
}
#butt{
 width: 100px;
}

</style>

<script>

function initializeScreen(){

 var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");

 var puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();

 for ( var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length ; i++ ) {
  var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
  var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
  for(var j = 0 ; j < rowData.length ; j++){
   var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
   if(rowData[j] != 0){
    cell.innerHTML = rowData[j];
   }else{
    cell.innerHTML = "1";
    cell.style.backgroundColor  = "black";
   }
  }
 }

}

function preparePuzzelArray(){
var items = [ [0, 0, 0, 0, '?', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, '?', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, '?', 0, '?', 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '?', 0, 0, 0, '?'],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   ];
return items;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initializeScreen()">
<div id="leftBox">
<table id="puzzel">
</table>
</div>
<div id="rightBox">
<table>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Clear All"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Check"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Solve"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Clue"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably JavaScript, I'm assuming it will have some sort of functionality.

Comment: yes it will, please see the image in the link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B00URazV5RS1djB2NFZrclMwb0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I saw it, do you have a question over something specific to the assignment? All you asked is whether to use JS or HTML for crossword.

Comment: I like more the second option, defining the puzzle with an array. It looks more extensible. But rememeber that this community is for asking more specific questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know I'm not supposed to do this, but I loved the challenge so I came with a solution in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7arnuq3y/2/)

It uses the following markup

```
<div id="puzzle_container">
    <table id="puzzle">
    </table>
</div>

<div id="hints_container">
    <h3>Vertical</h3>
        <div id="vertical_hints_container"></div>
    <h3>Horizontal</h3>
        <div id="horizontal_hints_container"></div>
</div>

<div id="buttons_container">
    <button id="clear_all">Clear All</button>
    <button id="check">Check</button>
    <button id="solve">Solve</button>
    <button id="clue">Clue</button>
</div>
```

And jQuery.

Comment: Wooooo! amazing work Alvaro Flaño Larrondo. I am only supposed to use JS. Really great work.

Comment: At least now I have a way to go. Cant thank you enough.

Comment: If you liked the answer and it was helpfull, please upvote it and select as the accepted answer for feedback for the author and for future references for people looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross word Puzzel</title>
<style>

#cross{
 text-align: center;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid white;
}
#buttons{
 width:30%;
 float: right;
}
tr{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
}
#leftBox{
 float: left;
}
#rightBox{
 float: left;
 clear:left;
}
.butt{
 height:50px;
 width: 107px;
}
#puzzel{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.inputBox{
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
#hintsTable{
 width: 480px;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
}
</style>

<script>
//Globals
var currentTextInput;
var puzzelArrayData;
//Loads the Crossword
function initializeScreen(){
 var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
 puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
 for ( var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length ; i++ ) {
  var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
  var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
  for(var j = 0 ; j < rowData.length ; j++){
   var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
   if(rowData[j] != 0){
    var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
    cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="inputBox" maxlength="1" style="text-transform: lowercase" ' + 'id="' + txtID + '" onfocus="textInputFocus(' + "'" + txtID + "'"+ ')">';
   }else{
    cell.style.backgroundColor  = "black";
   }
  }
 }
 addHint();
}
//Adds the hint numbers
function addHint(){
 document.getElementById("txt_0_4").placeholder = "1";
 document.getElementById("txt_2_6").placeholder = "2";
 document.getElementById("txt_3_1").placeholder = "3";
 document.getElementById("txt_3_9").placeholder = "4";
 document.getElementById("txt_6_2").placeholder = "5";
 document.getElementById("txt_9_0").placeholder = "6";
}
//Stores ID of the selected cell into currentTextInput
function textInputFocus(txtID123){
 currentTextInput = txtID123;
}
//Returns Array
function preparePuzzelArray(){
var items = [ [0, 0, 0, 0, 'p', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 'u', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 'n', 0, 'b', 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 'h', 'y', 'd', 'e', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'd'],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'n', 0, 0, 'e'],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'g', 0, 0, 'l'],
    [0, 0, 'm', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'a', 'i', 0, 'h'],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'l', 0, 0, 'i'],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'o', 0, 0, 0],
    ['k', 'a', 's', 'h', 'm', 'i','r', 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0]
   ];
return items;
}
//Clear All Button
function clearAllClicked(){
 currentTextInput = '';
 var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
 puzzelTable.innerHTML = '';
    initializeScreen();
}
//Check button
function checkClicked(){
 for ( var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length ; i++ ) {
  var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
  for(var j = 0 ; j < rowData.length ; j++){
   if(rowData[j] != 0){
    var selectedInputTextElement = document.getElementById('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
    if(selectedInputTextElement.value != puzzelArrayData[i][j]){
     selectedInputTextElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     
    }else{
     selectedInputTextElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
//Clue Button
function clueClicked(){
 if (currentTextInput != null){
  var temp1 = currentTextInput;
  var token = temp1.split("_");
  var row = token[1];
  var column = token[2];
  document.getElementById(temp1).value = puzzelArrayData[row][column];
  //checkClicked();
 }
}
//Solve Button
function solveClicked(){
 if (currentTextInput != null){
  var temp1 = currentTextInput;
  var token = temp1.split("_");
  var row = token[1];
  var column = token[2];
  
  // Print elements on top
  for(j = row; j >= 0; j--){
   if(puzzelArrayData[j][column] != 0){
    document.getElementById('txt' + '_' + j + '_' + column).value = puzzelArrayData[j][column];
    }else break;
  }
  // Print elements on right
  for(i = column; i< puzzelArrayData[row].length; i++){
   if(puzzelArrayData[row][i] != 0){
    document.getElementById('txt' + '_' + row + '_' + i).value = puzzelArrayData[row][i];
    }else break;
  }
  
  // Print elements below
  for(m = row; m< puzzelArrayData.length; m++){
   if(puzzelArrayData[m][column] != 0){
    document.getElementById('txt' + '_' + m + '_' + column).value = puzzelArrayData[m][column];
    }else break;
  }
  // Print elements on left
  for(k = column; k >= 0; k--){
   if(puzzelArrayData[row][k] != 0){
    document.getElementById('txt' + '_' + row + '_' + k).value = puzzelArrayData[row][k];
    }else break;
  }
  // Done!
  
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initializeScreen()">
<div id="leftBox">
<table id="puzzel">

</table>
</div>
<div id="rightBox">
<table>
 <tr><td><input class="butt"  type="submit" value="Clear All" onclick="clearAllClicked()"></td>
 <td><input class="butt"  type="submit" value="Check" onclick="checkClicked()"></td>
 <td><input class="butt"  type="submit" value="Solve" onclick="solveClicked()"></td>
 <td><input class="butt"  type="submit" value="Clue" onclick="clueClicked()"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<table id="hintsTable">
  <tr>
   <td><strong>Horizontal:</strong></td><td><strong>Vertical:</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3. Cultural Hub (Hyderabad)</td><td>1. Education Hub (Pune)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>5. India's financial capital (Mumbai)</td><td>2. Information Technology Hub (Bangalore)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>6. Saffron region (Kashmir)</td><td>4. Capital of India (Delhi)</td>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Done!! && Done!!
Thanks again Alvaro Flaño Larrondo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant.

It is under the MIT license. [Source](https://github.com/Piterden/vue-crossword/tree/master/)

[DEMO](https://piterden.github.io/vue-crossword)

Comment: DEMO: Could not find dependency: 'es6-loader' relative to '/package.json'

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross word Puzzel</title>
<style>
#puzzel {
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#cross{
 text-align: center;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid white;
}


#buttons{
 width:30%;
 float: right;

}
tr{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leftBox{
 float: left;
 width:50%
 height: 50%;
}
#rightBox{
 float: left;
}
#butt{
 width: 100px;
 padding:20px;
}
table{
 padding:20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftBox">
<table id="puzzel">
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross">?</td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
 <td id="cross" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="rightBox">
<table>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Clear All"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Check"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Solve"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input id="butt"  type="submit" value="Clue"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Exolve (https://github.com/viresh-ratnakar/exolve) for setting up interactively solvable crosswords very easily. Exolve is open source and free (MIT license).

With Exolve, setting up an interactively solvable crossword (with or without solutions provided) is something as simple as editing the following plain text within an HTML file:

```
<script>
const puzzleText = `
======REPLACE WITH YOUR PUZZLE BELOW======
exolve-begin
  exolve-width: 3
  exolve-height: 3
  exolve-grid:
    ACE
    R.R
    EAR
  exolve-across:
    1 Clue for ACE (3)
    3 Clue for EAR (3)
  exolve-down
    1 Clue for ARE (3)
    2 Clue for ERR (3)
exolve-end
======REPLACE WITH YOUR PUZZLE ABOVE======
`;
</script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks! I've now added inline details.